# Не получается создать сервер в Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql

Вообщем скачал Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio не могу зарегистрировать сервер зашёл на доку от майкрософта делал всё по инструкции не получилось все равно создать можете подсказать как решить данную проблему.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а что вы конкретно делали?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev ну я зашёл в группы локальных серверов -> Задачи -> Зарегистрировать лок.сервер  и мне пишет, что локальные серверы типа "Ядро СУБД" не найдены

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio это не сервер баз данных, это можно сказать SQL server UI client. Вам нужно установить сам SQL DB server.